# react history.push does not work neither does useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, spfx

I am wanting to redirect to another page on form submit.

I have read and seen several articles advising on using:

```
this.props.history.push("/")
```

As well as the suggestion to use:

```
import { useHistory  } from 'react-router-dom';
//Followed by
let history = useHistory();
history.push("/");
```

However neither work for me, the:

```
this.props.history.push("/")
```

Produces the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.props.history.push is not a function
```

And the usage of:

```
import { useHistory  } from 'react-router-dom';
//Followed by
let history = useHistory();
history.push("/");
```

produces the following error:

```
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_3b6fc7db2fe02279bf3499609f870638.js:69 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321
```

For reference, here is what my component looks like, no duplicate calls:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { HttpClient, AadHttpClient, SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfiguration, HttpClientResponse, ODataVersion, ISPHttpClientConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import styles from './MyChildComponent.module.scss';
import { MyChildComponentProps } from './MyChildComponentProps';
import { Form, Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import {
  FormikTextField,
  FormikDropdown,
} from 'formik-office-ui-fabric-react';
import { DefaultButton, PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { FormValuesValidation } from '../../utility/FormValuesValidation';
import { useHistory  } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class MyChildComponent extends React.Component<MyChildComponentProps, {}> {
  private error: Error = null;
 
  public constructor(props: MyChildComponentProps){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   };
 }

  public componentDidMount() {
          
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<MyChildComponentProps> {

    let formValues = new FormValuesValidation();
    formValues.assignment = this.props.memberID;
    formValues.fullname = this.props.name;
      
    return (
      <div className={ styles.MyChildComponent}>
        <div>
          <Formik
            initialValues={formValues}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              try{
                this.props.service.postMyForm(this.props.memberID, values)
                .then((result) => {
                 switch (result) {
                   case 200:
                      this.props.history.push("/");
                   case 500 : case 404: case 401:
                      this.props.history.push("/errorPage");
                   default:
                     break;
                 }
                },
                  (error: any) => {
                    console.log("Something really bad happened", error);
                  }
                );
              } catch (e) {
                console.log("an error occured", e);
                this.error = e;
              }
            }}
            render={({ values, touched, errors, ...props }) => (
              
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>

                  <Field
                    name="fullname"
                    label="Employee Name"
                    component={FormikTextField}
                    disabled
                  />

                  <Field
                    name="memberID"
                    label="Employee No"
                    component={FormikTextField}
                    disabled
                  />                  

                  <div style={{ marginTop: '1em' }}>
                    <PrimaryButton
                      type="submit"
                      disabled={!props.dirty || !props.isValid}
                    >
                      Submit
                    </PrimaryButton>
                    &nbsp;
                    <DefaultButton
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => props.resetForm()}
                      disabled={!props.dirty}
                    >
                      Reset
                    </DefaultButton>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The component I am trying to do this in is a child component and pass in history as a props to the component.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this.props.history.push({ pathname: "/" }); work?

Comment: You need to add some more context on how you're using these. Without seeing that all I can say is: hooks (like `useHistory`) can only be used in the body of **function components**. `this.props.history` is only available to you if you have wrapped the component with `withRouter` or defined your `Route` a certain way.

Comment: @rrd unfortunately no, same error: this.props.history is not a function.

Comment: I don't see `withRouter` being used, so unless this component is being passed `history` either by another one of your components, or though the route parameters directly from `Route`, then that is why this isn't working.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: @BrianThompson - thanks for the pointer Brian, it helped me resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You must use withRouter to be able to use the history object as stated in [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) doc:

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

So like the doc, you should do something like this:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const history = this.props.history;

    return <button onClick={() => {history.push("/")}}></button>;
  }
}

const YourComponentWithRouter = withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sajad, it pointed me in the right direction to resolve my issue! Although I had to convert my functional component to a class component first and also import RouteComponentProps

Answer (score 0):

So resolved this by converting my functional component into a class component and then importing:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
```

As I was receiving the following error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof MyChildComponent ' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>>'.
```

The error was due to the types as I am using Typescript, below is what my converted/completed code looks like, I had to extend my props to use RouteComponentProps:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { HttpClient, AadHttpClient, SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfiguration, HttpClientResponse, ODataVersion, ISPHttpClientConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import styles from './MyChildComponent.module.scss';
import { Form, Formik, Field } from 'formik';
import {
  FormikTextField,
  FormikDropdown,
} from 'formik-office-ui-fabric-react';
import { DefaultButton, PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { FormValuesValidation } from '../../utility/FormValuesValidation';
import { useHistory, withRouter, Redirect  } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { MyServices} from "../../../services/myservices/services";


class MyChildComponent extends React.Component<MyChildComponentProps> {
  private error: Error = null;
 
  public constructor(props: MyChildComponentProps){
   super(props);
 }

    public componentDidMount() {    

  }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<MyChildComponentProps> {
        let formValues = new FormValuesValidation();
    formValues.memberID= this.props.memberID;
    formValues.fullname = this.props.name;

    return (
<div className={ styles.MyChildComponent}>
        <div>
          <Formik
            initialValues={formValues}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              try{
                this.props.service.postForm(this.props.memberID, values)
                .then((result) => {
                 switch (result) {
                   case 200:
                     this.props.history.push("/");
                     break;
                   case 500 : case 404: case 401:
                      this.props.history.push("/errorPage");
                      break;
                   default:
                     break;
                 }
                },
                  (error: any) => {
                    console.log("Something really bad happened", error);
                  }
                );
              } catch (e) {
                console.log("an error occured", e);
                this.error = e;
              }
            }}
            render={({ values, touched, errors, ...props }) => (
              
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>

                  <Field
                    name="fullname"
                    label="Employee Name"
                    component={FormikTextField}
                    disabled
                  />

                  <Field
                    name="memberID"
                    label="Employee No"
                    component={FormikTextField}
                    disabled
                  />                      

                  <div style={{ marginTop: '1em' }}>
                    <PrimaryButton
                      type="submit"
                      disabled={!props.dirty || !props.isValid}
                    >
                      Submit
                    </PrimaryButton>
                    &nbsp;
                    <DefaultButton
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => props.resetForm()}
                      disabled={!props.dirty}
                    >
                      Reset
                    </DefaultButton>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

export interface MyChildComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  description: string;
  service: MyServices;
  memberID: string;
  name: string;
}

export default withRouter(MyChildComponent);
```